# Changing the color of the highlighted line in debugging mode

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, ide, colors, flash-builder

Thing is, after applying a new color theme for my Flash Builder enviroment, the only thing I couldnt find was an option to change the color when you enter in debug mode. When you have a brakpoint there, the color of that line change to light green, and I got dark background and white characters.. so, I dont see anything, I have to manually highlight the line.. really annoying.

I spend some minuts trying to change that color, but no luck so far, do anyone know where can I change that color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats is simple goto windows->preferences->Genral->Editors->TextEditors->Annotations where you can find the Debug Current Instruction Pointer. there you can find the color value for that.

change and Enjoy.

Comment: to anyone coming here looking for the line color of the line invoking current method while debugging in VB, it's `Visual Basic Read Only Marker`